# Magento2 How to reduce file size of invoice pdf (need to support Chinese and Korean characters)?

Tags: magento2.4, zend-framework, invoice-pdf, php8.1, magento2.4.4-p2

Because Magento OOTB can not support Chinese and Korean characters, so I use the external font file (this font https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif+HK?noto.query=Noto+Serif+HK) to do this. But because the font file is large (Its size is about 34M), it caused generated pdf file is also large (Its size is about 34M).

I checked the Magento OOTB codes, it uses \Zend_Pdf to generate pdf. And its codes is using Flate to compress the font file by default, this should be cut file size by about half, but actaully it is not.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know the reason? And any ideas to reduce the pdf size?